# What is the distinction between head.ready() and head.load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, head.js

Using the JS loader head.js I'm having a bit of a hard time distinguishing the subtle differences between head.ready() and head.load().

```
head.ready('jquery.js', function(){//Do something});
```

VS

```
head.load('jquery.js', function(){//Do something});
```

As far as I understand both seem to load 'jquery.js' and then perform a callback when it is loaded. However, in practice I get some edge cases where head.load doesn't work as expected in Firefox making me think I am not understanding where to use head.load and where to use head.ready.

Comment: [Link](http://headjs.com/) Its described clearly in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [API](http://headjs.com/site/api/v1.00.html) it seems like head.load loads the content, but head.ready is an Event Listener, you can also add a callback to head.load and would work too, but head.load is the only one who can actually load the resources, head.ready not.

**EDIT:** An example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="head.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // this loads jquery asyncrounously & in parallel
            head.load("jquery.min.js");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- some content-->

        <!-- injected via a module or an include -->
        <script>
            // some function that depends on jquery
            head.ready("jquery.min.js", function () {
                // this will only be executed once jquery has finished loading
                $(".main").hide();
            });
        </script>

        <!-- some content-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not how I understood it. head.ready does load in resources in my tests, but now I can see this probably isn't how it's intended to be used.